# Woocommerce module product misaligned

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how could I solve this? The product data module is misaligned instead of below it is on the side.
[image]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress metabox order and view can be modify by drag and drop of metabox.

This view of metabox will only use for particular user/admin. So you can drag drop them to bottom again.

I supposed that you can drag & drop metabox from metabox heading.

Comment: Hi Vicky Thank you very much for answering me, the truth is that this is the problem I cannot click and drag the module, the screen options tab does not work for me and neither do other plugins such as wp all import, the titles appear but when clicking they do not work.

Thank you